# LIbrary not loading in gae serverside

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I have a simple library which contains this file:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class DateUtils {
       public static Date addDays(Date date, int days) {
            assert date != null : "Date cannont be null";
              return new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + days);
        }

}
```

This is run a with gwt.  I call this function in the server and in the client.  It works perfectly in development mode.  When I upload it to gae it only works on the client side.

Error log says org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mt/utilities/shared/DateUtils

pom.xml added

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mt.ba</groupId>
  <artifactId>basicapp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>GWTP Basic with GXT</name>
  <description>Basic GWTP application with the GXT library</description>

  <properties>
    <!-- client -->
    <!-- Get the latest GXT release through support 3.0.6... -->
    <gxt.version>3.0.1</gxt.version>
    <gwt.version>2.5.1</gwt.version>
    <gwtp.version>1.1.1</gwtp.version>
    <gin.version>2.0.0</gin.version>

    <!-- server -->
    <guice.version>3.0</guice.version>

    <!-- REST -->
    <resteasy.version>3.0.2.Final</resteasy.version>
    <arcbees.version>1.1.1</arcbees.version>

    <!-- testing -->
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <!--
    <jukito.version>1.3</jukito.version>
 -->
    <!-- maven -->
    <gwt-maven-plugin.version>2.5.1</gwt-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.6</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>2.3.2</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-resources-plugin.version>2.5</maven-resources-plugin.version>
    <maven-processor-plugin.version>2.0.5</maven-processor-plugin.version>
    <maven-build-helper-plugin.version>1.7</maven-build-helper-plugin.version>

    <target.jdk>1.7</target.jdk>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>

    <!-- GAE -->
    <gae.version>1.8.8</gae.version>
    <gae.home>${settings.localRepository}/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/${gae.version}/appengine-java-sdk-${gae.version}</gae.home>

    <!-- mt Libraries -->
    <mt.rest>0.3.1</mt.rest>
    <mt.utilities>0.1.3</mt.utilities>

  </properties>

  <build>
    <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gae.version}</version>
            </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${target.jdk}</source>
          <target>${target.jdk}</target>
          <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- JUnit Testing - skip *.GwtTest cases -->
      <!-- 'mvn test' - runs the Junit tests -->
      <!-- 'mvn integration-test` - runs GWT test cases -->
      <!-- 'mvn integration-test -P selenium-local` - runs GWT selenium unit test cases -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
          </includes>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*GwtTest.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- GWT -->
      <!-- 'mvn gwt:run' - runs development mode -->
      <!-- 'mvn gwt:debug' - runs debug mode -->
      <!-- 'mvn gwt:compile' - compiles gwt -->
      <!-- 'mvn integration-test' - runs the gwt tests (*GwtTest.java) -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>true</gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>
          <strict>true</strict>

          <testTimeOut>180</testTimeOut>
          <includes>**/*GwtTestSuite.java</includes>
          <excludes>**/*GwtTest.java</excludes>
          <mode>htmlunit</mode>

          <extraJvmArgs>-Xss1024K -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M</extraJvmArgs>
          <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
          <style>${gwt.style}</style>

          <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
          <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>

          <runTarget>ba.html</runTarget>
          <modules>
            <module>com.mt.ba.ba</module>
          </modules>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>RestLibrary</id>
        <url>https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45032161/mvn-repository/com/mt/rest/restlibrary/${mt.rest}/restlibrary-${mt.rest}.jar</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>UtilitiesLibrary</id>
        <url>https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45032161/mvn-repository/com/mt/utilities/utilitieslibrary/${mt.utilities}/utilitieslibrary-${mt.utilities}.jar</url>
    </repository>
    </repositories>


  <!-- Get the latest release through support, 3.0.6... -->
  <!-- <repositories> -->
    <!-- <repository> -->
      <!-- ~/.m2/settings.xml add <server/> with same id here with login credentials -->
      <!-- <id>sencha-gxt-repository</id> -->
      <!-- <name>Sencha GXT Repository</name> -->
      <!-- Support Subscribers Only: Subscribe to support for -->
      <!-- Latest GPL Support GXT Versions -->
      <!-- <url>https://maven.sencha.com/repo/gxt-support-gpl-release</url> -->
      <!-- Commercial Support GXT Versions -->
      <!-- <url>https://maven.sencha.com/repo/gxt-commercial-release</url> -->
    <!-- </repository> -->
  <!-- </repositories> -->

  <dependencies>

    <!-- mt Libraries -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mt.rest</groupId>
        <artifactId>restlibrary</artifactId>
        <version>${mt.rest}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mt.utilities</groupId>
        <artifactId>utilitieslibrary</artifactId>
        <version>${mt.utilities}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- GXT -->
    <!-- http://docs.sencha.com/gxt-guides/3/ -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gxt</artifactId>
      <version>${gxt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gxt-chart</artifactId>
      <version>${gxt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Google Web Toolkit -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <version>${gwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- GWT-Platform -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwtp-mvp-client</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- AppEngine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${gae.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>


    <!-- DI -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
      <version>${guice.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${guice.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice-assistedinject</artifactId>
      <version>${guice.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>gin</artifactId>
      <version>${gin.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Rest -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwtp-dispatch-rest</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>



    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<!--
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jukito</groupId>
      <artifactId>jukito</artifactId>
      <version>${jukito.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
 -->
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
      <version>2.33.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.33.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <profiles>
    <!-- run with 'mvn integration-test -P selenium-local' -->
    <profile>
      <id>selenium-local</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <mode>selenium</mode>
              <productionMode>true</productionMode>
              <selenium>localhost:4444/*firefox,localhost:4444/*opera</selenium>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using Maven? Ant? Eclipse? The problem may be in your project setup.

Comment: Thank you Gilberto, I am using Maven and just added my pom.xml file.  I use Eclipse to upload to the gae

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your DateUtils code is uploaded to GAE.
You maybe have a War Server Project, and a Client Projet.
And you just deploy the War Server Projet to the serveur with just the GWT compiled files ?

The best is to have a shared project who is included in both project.

Comment: Thanks Partice, I just added my pom.xml and upload with the gwt plugin in Eclipse.  When I look at my target/WEB-INF/lib directory the library is there.  It works fine on the client side on the gae just not the server side and in development mode it works fine on both the server and client side.